# Replicating _mm256_shuffle_epi8 Intrinsic With Java Vector API Shuffle?

Tags: java, vectorization, simd, avx2, project-panama

I am (mostly for fun) attempting to write a SHA-256 digest function using Java's Vector API. I am using the following AVX2 implementation from bitcoin as a reference:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7fcf53f7b4524572d1d0c9a5fdc388e87eb02416/src/crypto/sha256_avx2.cpp

I have been able to make it to the point where the shuffle intrinsic is used: `return _mm256_shuffle_epi8(ret, _mm256_set_epi32(0x0C0D0E0FUL, 0x08090A0BUL, 0x04050607UL, 0x00010203UL, 0x0C0D0E0FUL, 0x08090A0BUL, 0x04050607UL, 0x00010203UL));`.

I see that the Java Vector API provides a `VectorShuffle` class and `rearrange` methods on the `Vector` class but the API docs seem to be approaching shuffles from the angle of indexes and not masks.

So my question is - how to replicate (as close as possible) the behavior of the `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` intrinsic with Java's vector API?

Update: I just realized that the AVX2 SHA-256 bitcoin implementation seems to be a Double SHA-256 implementation. This complicates matters...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java SIMD, but the control vector for `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` *is* a vector of indices: for that byte of the destination, index one of the 16 bytes of (this half of) the source.  (With additional functionality of zeroing the output byte if the high bit is set in the control vector.)  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb.

Comment: Normally you'd write `pshufb` control vectors with `_mm256_setr_epi8` (or set instead of setr), unless 4-byte groups are morenatural for some reason.  Perhaps it's slightly natural here, with the high 8 bytes of the vector being (highest) 12,13,14,15, 8,9,10,11 (lowest), so a byte-reverse within each 32-bit dword.  So writing the shuffle for each dword as a 32-bit hex value makes some sense.  (Not posting as an answer because it's not clear what you mean by "not masks", and I don't know how to write the same thing in Java's SIMD API.)

Comment: My verbiage reflects my confusion with SIMD. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: It may be as simple as:

        IntVector ret = IntVector.fromArray(SPECIES_256, new int[] { chunk[7], chunk[6], chunk[5], chunk[4], chunk[3],
                chunk[2], chunk[1], chunk[0] }, offset);
       ret.rearrange(VectorShuffle.fromArray(SPECIES_256, new int[] {0x0C0D0E0F, 0x08090A0B, 0x04050607, 0x00010203, 0x0C0D0E0F, 0x08090A0B, 0x04050607, 0x00010203}, 0));
    }

Comment: It's a shuffle *within* each int, an endian-swap of each 32-bit int element separately.  So probably you need a byte vector, not an IntVector.  I'm guessing that reaarange use those ints as (way out of range) selectors for the int elements across the whole vector, like AVX2 `vpermd` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermd:vpermw).

Comment: Indeed - my above attempt yields: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: required an index in [0..7] but found -1 - not 100% sure how to implement it using ByteVector. Hopefully someone will answer :)

Comment: Doesn't ByteVector have a similar `rearrange`?  Or does it not efficiently expose the in-lane (within 16-byte halves) behaviour of `vpshufb`, instead forcing you to program it like it was AVX-512VBMI `vpermb` where each index is an index into the full 32 byte vector, not into its own half?  If it helps, that `_mm256_set_epi32` is *exactly* equivalent to `_mm256_set_epi8(12,13,14,15,  8,9,10,11, ... )`, or using setr whose args are in array initializer order, `_mm256_setr_epi8(..., 11,10,9,8, 15,14,13,12)` .